# Rails: How do I order a Table by its most recently created associated Table value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a basic Rails-API app with two tables:

- Student(name, age)
- Exams(score, created_at)

Student has_many exams. Exam belongs_to one Student.

I'd like to order(desc) Students by score based only on their most recently created Exam. Here's kind of what I'm thinking:

```
@students = Student.all.includes(:exams).order...????
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does every student has exam? If not, then what will be there position in the list(starting or ending)?

Comment: Every student has an exam, but in the case that they don't I'd like them to be at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try like:

```
Student.all.joins(:exams).order("exams.created_at DESC, exams.score DESC")
```

But, I think there is much better way to do it.

Comment: I wasn't able to call exams.score. I did however, find an uglier solution to my problem, which I've posted. But thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
Student.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN `exams` on `students`.`id` = `exams`.`student_id`')
.order("`exams`.`created_at` DESC, `exams`.`score` DESC")
```

because `inner join` will skip those students who will not have any exams.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kuldeep. I wasn't able to call exams.score. I did however, find an uglier solution to my problem, which I've posted.

Comment: @LeeCarl: What is the error if you were trying to execute above query? I have tested the aforementioned query on my end and it is working fine. May be I am missing something. So can you please post the error which you have received after execution of above SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really ugly way to do it... but...

```
@students = Student.all
sort_this = []
@students.each do |student|
  sort_this << { student => student.exams.order('created_at DESC').first }
end
@sorted = sort_this.sort_by! { |hash| hash.values.first.score }.reverse!
```

I could go on and extract only the hash keys if I want a collection of sorted Students only.